# Iniciar sesion con Curl - Error Captcha header

Tags: php, javascript, json, curl

Hola que tal estoy intentando iniciar sesion en una pagina web externa desde php, el formulario de inicio de sesion esta escrito en Javascript, despues de mucha investigacion con [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) encontre el url al que se envian las contraseñas el cual es una api, pero al ejecutar el codigo me arroja el error:

```
{"result":"Captcha Header Validation Failed","error_code":"INVALID_PASSWORD"}
```

Claramente dice que el password es incorrecto pero no es asi, ya se verifico y es la correcta, creo que el error reside en otro lado, La pagina no proporciona documentacion Api por lo que me encuentro solo intentando descifrar como iniciar sesion desde php y curl, aqui les dejo mi codigo y espero puedan ayudarme a ver en que estoy mal

```
<?php 
    $url = 'https://www.textnow.com/api/sessions'; //URL en la que iniciare sesion
    $ch = curl_init();
    $parametros_post = 'username='.urlencode("AquiMiNombreDeUsuario").'&password='.urlencode("AquiMiPassword");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Language: es-es,en"));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parametros_post);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $parametros_post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $parametros_post);

    //Guardar página
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    //Comprobar si ha hecho login en la página
    echo $result;

  $JSONData = 
  file_get_contents("https://www.textnow.com/api/users/AquiMiNombreDeUsuario");
  $dataObject = json_decode($JSONData);
  echo "<b> Usuario: </b>", $dataObject->sip_username;
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<b> Password: </b>", $dataObject->sip_password;
  ?>
```

Una disculpa si no me explico claramente, Mi objetivo es iniciar sesion en esta pagina www.textnow.com/login para obtener las contraseñas voip de mi usuario que se encuentran en este URL https://www.textnow.com/api/users/AquiMiNombreDeUsuario pero que estan restringidas por inicio de sesion.

Comment: Cuando veo ese mensaje lo que parece es que la página espera que resuelvas un captcha para darte acceso, **además del usuario y contraseña habitual de inicio de sesión**. Y por supuesto, el objetivo del captcha es precisamente evitar el tipo de acceso que estás haciendo (por programa en vez de como usuario), así que no habrá una solución fácil.

Comment: Significa que no es posible? porque cuando ingreso al url de inicio de sesion no aparece ningun captcha para verificar

Comment: Para pasar el nombre de usuario y la clave, tienes que usar el parámetro que `cURL` tiene para ello que es [`CURLOPT_USERPWD`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt.php)
, por ejemplo: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "AquiMiNombreDeUsuario:AquiMiPassword");` y es posible que haya que indicar un modo de autenticación, por ejemplo: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);` o algo así. Ya que dices que es una API, ellos debes indicarte qué código hay que usar y cómo para hacer lo que queires.

Comment: Gracias @cedano, realice las modificaciones pero sigue ejecutando el mismo error, simplemente no inicia la sesion